# Efficient way to find count of duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I am having only basic knowledge of `SQL` and this is my first for the tag SQL, so pardon me if I miss something in the first instance.  There is a large database having, one table which is of particular interest, consists of more than 100 Million rows.  Client is using `PostgreSQL` for database.

The structure of this table is something like this (sample data) table name say `table`

```
  biometric_token ID status State_code
1            ABCD  1      A          1
2            ABCD  2      R          2
3            ABCD  3      A          2
4            BCDE  4      A          1
5            DEFG  5      A          2
6            DEFG  6      A          2
7            DEFG  7      A          3
8            FGHI  8      A          4
```

- column `biometric_token` is biometric based id which I can safely assume is really unique per person and he/she cannot fake it.  Needless to say, this token is collected in end of the registration process to which other three columns pertain.
- `ID` is system generated unique ID given to every individual when he/she approach for registration.
- `status` is either `approved - A` or `rejected - R`.
- `State_code` is code of state/county in which individual is registered.

What I need is to find how many (count only) individuals (i.e. having same biometric_token) have been registered more than once.  So the output format be something like

```
  count_of_individuals number_of_times
1                    1               3
2                    1               2
```

Explanation

- `ABCD` successfully registered 2 times
- `DEFG` successfully registered 3 times

---

Code (nested query) that I have tried, that's working but very slow, is given below.  I need to find if there is any faster alternative which can successfully retrieve this summary from this huge database

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT biometric_token) AS count_of_individuals, cnt AS number_of_times
FROM

(SELECT biometric_token, count (ID) AS cnt
FROM table
WHERE status IN ('A')
GROUP BY biometric_token
HAVING cnt > 1)

GROUP BY number_of_times
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably also have suggested your current query.  But, we can try adding the following index to your table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (status, biometric_token);
```

This index should cover the entire query, and would at least allow Postgres to only have to aggregate over a subset of the table consisting of the approved registration records.

Comment: can you please explain a bit further, as to what it will do exactly and after creating this index, how I'll have to proceed or change my select query

Comment: @AnilGoyal A full explanation of how a B-tree index works in SQL is out of scope for a single question/answer.  The first column in the index `status` will immediately let Postgres discard any records other than those which have been approved.  The second column `biometric_token` is there to allow Postgres to do the aggregation using the index alone.

Comment: _how I'll have to proceed or change my select query_ You don't have to change your select query. 99% of the time it uses the index automatically